# jQuery nested accordion - disable auto open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, accordion

I am trying to make it so that the accordion (`#subAccordion1`) within the parent (`#accordion`) is closed by default (note: there is only one subAccordion).

I am having some trouble doing this..

Here is my jQuery that I have tried:

```
$(function() {
    $("#accordion, #subAccordion1").accordion(function() {
        autoHeight: false
        active: false
        collapsible: true
    });
});
```

And my HTML:

```
<div id = "accordion">
     <h1>Accordion1:</h1>
     <div>
         <p>Blah</p>

         <div id = "subAccordion1">
             <h1>Accordion1.1</h1>
             <div>
                 <p> BLAH BLAH BLAH</p>
             </div>
         </div>
      <h1>Accordion2:</h1>
      <div>
           <p>Blah</p>
      </div>
</div>
```

The 2 outer accordions (1 and 2) are working as intended just the inner one (1.1) is automatically expanded!

Thanks for any help

Comment: Do you have jsfiddle link?

Comment: may we assume your missing `</div>` is a typo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fix your HTML first (missing closing div):

```
<div id = "accordion">
     <h1>Accordion1:</h1>
     <div>
         <p>Blah</p>
         <div id = "subAccordion1">
             <h1>Accordion1.1</h1>
             <div>
                 <p> BLAH BLAH BLAH</p>
             </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <h1>Accordion2:</h1>
      <div>
           <p>Blah</p>
      </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(function() {
  // init parent accordion
  $("#accordion").accordion( { heightStyle: "content" });

  // init sub accordion via #id selector with options object
  $("#subAccordion1").accordion({
                autoHeight: false,
                active: false,
                collapsible: true,
                heightStyle: "content"
   });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$("#accordion, #subAccordion1").accordion({
```

instead of

```
$("#accordion, #subAccordion1").accordion(function() {
```

Comment: One other problem that has now occurred .. the sub accordion is very small (i.e. only one line) so I have to scroll if I put multiple lines of text in as it only shows one at a time.. Correct me if I am wrong but I thought the autoHeight: false, should have addressed that?

Comment: Try with: $("#subAccordion1").accordion({
        autoHeight: false,
        active: false,
        collapsible: true,
        heightStyle: "content"
    });